# bashrc, PS1 formatting for change tilde to blank

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

PS1 is declared three times in `.bashrc`
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuiGf.png)

The command prompt says: `pradeep@home:~$`
[prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ4nQ.png)

How to make it say: `pradeep@home` ?

Comment: Please do not link to screen shots (they may disappear any time and are one more link to click to understand your problem). It is much better to cut and paste the actual text in your question.

Comment: I will keep it in mind. I did it to show colour.

Comment: Your title says to change the tilde to a **dot**, but there is no dot where you explain how the prompt should look like.  Also it is not clear to me, under what condition you want the dot to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the assignments to `PS1='\u@\h '` or place this last in the particular startup file.

An excellent resource to read that will make you a shell guru is `man bash`, which has all the details about PS1 magic and startup file search sequence.

Comment: `PS1='\u@\h ` has no color.

Comment: `PS1='\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0m\]' `made the text green. Thank you.